# MVC4 AntiForgery token cookie name is appended with random string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I am encountering an issue with MVC4's

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

html helper. On my development machine, when I run the project, upon inspecting the headers (using Fiddler) , the name of the token returned is

```
__RequestVerificationToken
```

But when deployed to an IIS version 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2), then token name looks like:

```
__RequestVerificationToken_L2V6b3JkZXI1
```

Where is this getting changed? Is it because my application is not deployed to the "root folder" of the IIS? E.g. my application is deployed to

```
"http://myserver/myapp" instead of "http://myserver"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer after looking at the source code:

```
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiForgeryConfig.cs
```

Yes, because my application was deployed to a path, the following code below appends the encoded equivalent of the path... Hope this finding will save you trouble.

```
        // If the app path is provided, we're generating a cookie name rather than a field name, and the cookie names should
    // be unique so that a development server cookie and an IIS cookie - both running on localhost - don't stomp on
    // each other.
    internal static string GetAntiForgeryCookieName(string appPath)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(appPath) || appPath == "/")
        {
            return AntiForgeryTokenFieldName;
        }
        else
        {
            return AntiForgeryTokenFieldName + "_" + HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appPath));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What can we do to solve this . sorry as I am adding comments to a very old thread

Comment: can you please specify the steps that you did to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Resolution to this problem is very easy by the use of AntiForgeryConfig class.See the reference below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.antiforgeryconfig?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2

```
Namespace:System.Web.Helpers
```

You need to add below code under Application_Start() event of Global.asax file.

```
if (AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName.Contains("__RequestVerificationToken"))
            {
                AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "__RequestVerificationToken";
            }
```